# Using openmp parallel loops in multiple independent threads

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, task, openmp

I have `#pragma omp parallel for` in multiple independent threads, but I am not sure that those parallel regions can run concurrently at the same time.

It would be inconvenient to change those regular threads to omp task regions.

So is it possible to execute two OpenMP parallel regions in two separate threads concurrently or may only one region run at a time?

#### Example:

```c
void f1()// executed in thread 1  
{  
#pragma omp parallel for  
for(...)  
    {/*do something*/}  
}  
void f2()//executed in thread 2  
{  
#pragma omp parallel for  
for(...)  
    {/*do something else*/}  
}
```

So my question is: will the parallel loops in `f1()` and `f2()` run concurrently at the same time having twice as many threads in total as OpenMP uses for one parallel region, or, it will run only one parallel block at a time and another will be waiting on a semaphore?

Comment: Can you please show some code?

Comment: I'm sorry, I couldn't make the formatting rules work. I hope you understand what I wanted to say.

Comment: Edit your question. After you paste your code select it and hit ctrl-k. That will auto-format your code. Fix any problems by hand. Nobody is going to take your question serious unless you spend the time time to do this.

Comment: It turns out that the formatting works only in the original question text, but it doesn't work in the comments.

Comment: How do you plan to run each function in seperate threads?

Comment: Each function f1() and f2() runs in an infinite loop each in it's own thread.
I am running it now and everything seems OK, but I'm not sure that those two teams really run concurrently - how can I check it in a profiler?
Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry, one thing I didn't tell is that those two threads are not logically independent: they are doing producer-consumer pattern.
So I can't just turn off second one and see how fast the first one alone.
Probably, I have to program a separate test with two really independent threads each doing OpenMP parallel for. I'll let you know how it worked. Thanks!

Comment: How do you create the two threads? Pthreads?

Comment: No, it's a windows project, I have to use winapi _beginthreadex(...) functions.

Comment: Doing so goes outside of what the OpenMP standard specifies. Your question is basically a duplicate of [Can I safely use OpenMP with C++11?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13837696/can-i-safely-use-openmp-with-c11)