# Optimizing a loop for MD-calculations

Tags: c++, optimization, openmp

I have the following loop I use for the force calculations in a MD-simulation:

```
struct data_str{
    int a = 0, b = 0;
    data_str(int a, int b) : a(a), b(b)
    {

    };
};

void work_func_both(std::vector<data_str> *data, int dist)
{
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < data->size()-1; i++)
    {
        for(unsigned int j = i+1; j < data->size(); j++)
        {
            if(abs((*data)[i].a - (*data)[j].a) < dist)
                {
                    (*data)[i].b += 3;
                    (*data)[j].b -= 1;
                }
        }
    }
}
```

It is a reduced version of the force-calculation loop I have in my application. My main problem is: It takes time, especially for larger vectors to calculate everything. Thus I wanted to optimize it, and tested the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>

#define VECTOR_SIZE 1e3
#define ROUNDS 1e5

struct data_str{
    int a = 0, b = 0;
    data_str(int a, int b) : a(a), b(b)
    {

    };
};

void work_func_both(std::vector<data_str> *data, int dist)
{
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < data->size()-1; i++)
    {
        #pragma omp parallel for
        for(unsigned int j = i+1; j < data->size(); j++)
        {
            if(abs((*data)[i].a - (*data)[j].a) < dist)
                {
                    (*data)[i].b += 3;
                    (*data)[j].b -= 1;
                }
        }
    }
}

void work_func_first(std::vector<data_str> *data, int dist)
{
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < data->size()-1; i++)
    {
        for(unsigned int j = i+1; j < data->size(); j++)
        {
            if(abs((*data)[i].a - (*data)[j].a) < dist)
                {
                    (*data)[i].b += 3;
                    (*data)[j].b -= 1;
                }
        }
    }
}

void work_func_second(std::vector<data_str> *data, int dist)
{
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < data->size()-1; i++)
    {
        #pragma omp parallel for
        for(unsigned int j = i+1; j < data->size(); j++)
        {
            if(abs((*data)[i].a - (*data)[j].a) < dist)
                {
                    (*data)[i].b += 3;
                    (*data)[j].b -= 1;
                }
        }
    }
}

void work_func_none(std::vector<data_str> *data, int dist)
{
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < data->size()-1; i++)
    {
        for(unsigned int j = i+1; j < data->size(); j++)
        {
            if(abs((*data)[i].a - (*data)[j].a) < dist)
                {
                    (*data)[i].b += 3;
                    (*data)[j].b -= 1;
                }
        }
    }
}


int main(void)
{
    std::vector<data_str> counter_vec1, counter_vec2, counter_vec3, counter_vec4;

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < VECTOR_SIZE; i++)
    {
        counter_vec1.push_back(data_str(i, i));
        counter_vec2.push_back(data_str(i, i));
        counter_vec3.push_back(data_str(i, i));
        counter_vec4.push_back(data_str(i, i));
    }
    omp_set_num_threads(8);
    const int length = 2;
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for(int i = 0; i < ROUNDS; i++)
    {
        work_func_both(&counter_vec1, length);
    }
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration_both = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(t2-t1).count();

    t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for(int i = 0; i < ROUNDS; i++)
    {
        work_func_first(&counter_vec2, length);
    }
    t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration_first = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(t2-t1).count();

    t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for(int i = 0; i < ROUNDS; i++)
    {
        work_func_second(&counter_vec3, length);
    }
    t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration_second = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(t2-t1).count();

    t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for(int i = 0; i < ROUNDS; i++)
    {
        work_func_none(&counter_vec4, length);
    }
    t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration_none = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(t2-t1).count();

    std::cout << "Both took " << duration_both/ROUNDS << ", first took " << duration_first/ROUNDS << ", second took " << duration_second/ROUNDS << " and none took " << duration_none/ROUNDS << '\n';
    return 0;
};
```

Compilation line is

```
 g++-5 -std=c++14 -O3 -fopenmp main.cpp -lgomp -o main
```

and the resulting output is

```
Both took 593.704, first took 547.549, second took 3394.53 and none took 856.049
```

My problem is now: Why is only the `_second()`-function returning correct results when comparing to the original version, and why is it so much slower in comparison to all the other loops? How could I optimize that loop for making it faster in total?

Comment: It looks like you're missing some synchronization while accessing data by multiple threads in _first(). Assume you have 2 threads and at some moment of time: 1st one is performing comparison between i=0, j=4 and 2dn one between i=4, j=6. If 1st thread consider modifying data[4] you'll have a data race and unpredictable result.

Comment: How can I sync the data in that case?

Comment: probably, the same data race occurs for _both()

Comment: I'm not too familiar with openmp, sorry. At least, try to redesign algorithm to avoid accessing the same data indexes by multiple threads.

Comment: for example, it you have several data vectors to process, you could let each thread operate on its data vector exclusively. In other words, parallelize queries (vectors) processing, not bytes inside single vector.

Comment: I can only have one vector, if not, then I would have to have access to all vectors in the same function. The function has to check all molecules if they are in range.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33053581/5239503) for addressing / optimizing such a code.