# Destructor isn't called for all thread_local objects

Tags: c++, multithreading, gcc, openmp

I work with OpenMP under GCC 6.2.0 and C++1z. I tried to use `thread_local` objects that are created inside threads when they are needed. `thread_local` objects work almost fine but it seems that destructors are called for only one thread. I can simulate the issue with the following code. Is the code using some unallowed feature or is there possibly some issue with the GCC implementation?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <sstream>

std::mutex g_cerr_mutex;

struct X {
    std::string name_;

    X() {
            std::stringstream ss;
            ss << std::this_thread::get_id();
            name_ = ss.str();
    }

    ~X() noexcept {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(g_cerr_mutex);
            std::cerr << "Destructing: " << name_ << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(void) {
    static thread_local std::unique_ptr<X> ptr;

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (unsigned x = 0; x < 32; ++x) {
            if (!ptr) {
                    ptr.reset(new X);
            }
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(g_cerr_mutex);
            std::cerr << std::this_thread::get_id() << " : " <<  static_cast<void*>(ptr.get()) << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Code is compiled and build under linux with 4-core i7 CPU. Commands for the compilation look this way:

```
$ g++ -std=gnu++1z -fopenmp -Wall -Werror -Ofast -pthread -c omp.cpp 
$ g++ -std=gnu++1z -fopenmp -Wall -Werror -Ofast -pthread omp.o -o omp
```

Output of the programm looks this way:

```
139868398491392 : 0x7f35780008c0 
139868398491392 : 0x7f35780008c0 
139868398491392 : 0x7f35780008c0 
139868398491392 : 0x7f35780008c0 
139868453738496 : 0x7bc2d0 
139868453738496 : 0x7bc2d0 
139868453738496 : 0x7bc2d0 
139868453738496 : 0x7bc2d0 
139868423669504 : 0x7f35880008c0 
139868423669504 : 0x7f35880008c0 
139868423669504 : 0x7f35880008c0 
139868423669504 : 0x7f35880008c0 
139868406884096 : 0x7f35700008c0 
139868406884096 : 0x7f35700008c0 
139868406884096 : 0x7f35700008c0 
139868406884096 : 0x7f35700008c0 
139868432062208 : 0x7f35a00008c0 
139868432062208 : 0x7f35a00008c0 
139868432062208 : 0x7f35a00008c0 
139868432062208 : 0x7f35a00008c0 
139868390098688 : 0x7f35900008c0 
139868390098688 : 0x7f35900008c0 
139868390098688 : 0x7f35900008c0 
139868390098688 : 0x7f35900008c0 
139868415276800 : 0x7f35980008c0 
139868415276800 : 0x7f35980008c0 
139868415276800 : 0x7f35980008c0 
139868415276800 : 0x7f35980008c0 
139868381705984 : 0x7f35800008c0 
139868381705984 : 0x7f35800008c0 
139868381705984 : 0x7f35800008c0 
139868381705984 : 0x7f35800008c0 
Destructing: 139868453738496
```

Obviously only one destructor is called.

Comment: How many constructors are called?

Comment: Thread local and thread pools is a surefire way to create memory leaks and other fun problems.

Comment: OpenMP has it's own means of declaring thread-local variables using `#pragma omp threadlocal(...)`. It is often (but not always!) implementation-compatible with the language constructs, e.g., the same TLS mechanism is used, but the semantics differ. Do not mix OpenMP and C++ threading!

Comment: BTW, have you tried running the same code with `std::thread`? No destructor is called at all. In the OpenMP case thread 0 is the main thread, therefore you get the destructor called once at the end of the serial part. GCC uses ELF TLS to implement thread-local variables, which, as far as I recall, doesn't (or at least used to not) support constructors and destructors, therefore GCC only allows PODs as thread-local variables. This is exposed in GCC's OpenMP `threadprivate` - if you try something like `#pragma omp threadprivate(ptr)` instead of `thread_local`, GCC throws an error.

Comment: Hristo, you are right. With std::thread, it doesn't call destructor either, only constructors...

Comment: Karoly, it seems that all constructors (8 in my case) are called.

Answer (score 0):

Mixing C++ language threading features and OpenMP is not well-defined. (See [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13837696/can-i-safely-use-openmp-with-c11) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41309299/mixing-c11-atomics-and-openmp)). Basically OpenMP only refers to C++98, so the interaction with OpenMP  and `threadlocal` is not safe/portable. It is usually assumed that it will work, because implementations do the right thing, but in this case apparently they do not. BTW: I can reproduce the same issue with Intel compiler / OpenMP runtime.

The safe and portable approach is to stick to either pure C++17 or OpenMP. With OpenMP, this means to define `ptr` as private:

```
static std::unique_ptr<X> ptr;
#pragma omp parallel
{
    ptr.reset();
    #pragma omp for
    for (unsigned x = 0; x < 32; ++x) {
```

Note that the `reset` is necessary, otherwise the value of `ptr` are undefined. You cannot use `firstprivate` as `std::unique_ptr` has no copy-ctor.